# How is this proof correct in regard to a $k$-subalgebra (Eisenbud)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, graded-rings

This is testing my understanding of algebras, subalgebras, & polynomial rings.

Page 31.

> **Corollary 1.5.**  *Let $k$ be a field, and let $S = k[x_1, \dots, x_r]$ be a polynomial graded by degree. Let $R$ be a $k$-subalgebra of $S$.  If $R$ is a summand of $S$, in the sense that there is a map of $R$-modules $\varphi: S \to R$ that preserves degrees and takes each element of $R$ to itself, then $R$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra.*
>
> *Proof.* Let $\hat{m} \subset R$ be the ideal generated by the homogeneous elements of $R$ of strictly positive degree.  Since $S$ is Noetherian, the ideal $\hat{m}S$ has a finite set of generators, which may be chosen to be homogeneous elements $f_1, \dots, f_s$ of $\hat{m}$.  We shall show that these elements generate $R$ as a $k$-algebra.
>     To do this, let $R'$ be the $k$-subalgebra of $S$ generated by $f_1, \dots, f_s$, and suppose $f \in R$.  We shall show that $f \in R'$ by induction on the degree of $f$.  To start the induction, note that if degree $f = 0$, then $f \in k \subset R'$, as claimed.
>     **Now suppose $\deg f \gt 0$, so that $f \in \hat{m}$.**  Since the $f_i$ generate $\hat{m}S$ as an ideal of $S$, we may write $f = \sum g_if_i$, where each $g_i$ is a homogeneous form of degree $\deg g_i = \deg f - \deg f_i \lt \deg f$. [...].

1. Is the bolded part an erratum in Eisenbud?  Shouldn't it be $\hat{m}S$ there?
2. How is each $g_i$ homogeneous?

Comment: Remember that you started with $f \in R$. Since $f$ has positive degree in $R$, it is in the ideal generated by homogeneous things of positive degree in $R$, namely $f \in \hat{m}$. Once $f \in \hat{m}$, of course it is in $\hat{m}S$ since $f = f * 1$.

Comment: For your second question: The ideal $\hat{m}S$ is generated by homogeneous elements. This is equivalent to $\hat{m}S$ being a graded $S$-module. I haven't worked through the details, but this is probably how you can get that the $g_i$ are homogeneous.

Comment: An «erratum» is a correction of an error, not an error. So no, that is not an erratum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Ken Duna.

According to [first properties of a graded ring:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#First_properties)
*A homogeneous ideal is the direct sum of its homogeneous parts.*

*Proof*.  Let $I \subset S$ be a homogeneous ideal (which clearly $\hat{m}S$ is).

Define the $n$th **homogeneous part** of $I$ to be $S_n \cap I$, where $S = S_0 \oplus S_1 \oplus \cdots$.  I want to show that $I = \bigoplus$ of its homogeneous parts.

Clearly the intersection of the modules $S_n \cap I, n\geq 0$ since $S_n = $ polynomials of degree $n$.  And clearly a finite sum of $s_0 + s_1 + \dots \in I$, where $s_i \in S_i \cap I$.  Thus I want to show that $I \subset \bigoplus S_n \cap I$.  This is also obvious.

In regard to my question, since $\hat{m}S = I$ is graded by degree we can write each $f \in I$ as $f = \sum_i^s g_i f_i$ where each $g_i$ is a homogeneous form.  This is where I am stuck.  Supposedly $g_i$ is homogeneous.

**Conjecture**: If $f \in \hat{m}$, then $f = \sum g_i f_i$ where each $g_i$ is homogeneous.

Comment: Your conjecture is true if $f$ is homogeneous and each $f_i$ is homogeneous. (In that case, we can take $g_i$ to be homogeneous of degree $\deg f - \deg f_i$. All the other degree parts of the $g_i$s must lead to cancellations. So we can just replace each $g_i$ with its $(\deg f - \deg f_i)$ part.) Eisenbud is pretty clear that the $f_i$ are homogeneous. What you quoted from Eisenbud, above, does not say explcitly that $f$ is homogeneous; it probably should.